# Gmaps v3 remove and dispose MVCObject

Tags: google-maps-api-3

What is the better way to remove and dispose one MVCObject including unbinds and clearing all events and markers ?. I have tried clearing markers and unbindAll() but the object is not removed of the map. Try with this [sample](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might not have the right understanding of the MVCObject.

But if you implement a OverlayView which is a MVCObject then to remove it from a map you need to call setMap(null); and then if you expose a onRemove function that will be called and in that you can clean up all your events.

Is that what you were looking for?